# How to get a current location on map after clicking button in android project?

Tags: android, android-maps

I am new to android, I need your help. I have two edit text entered latitude and longitude and a button searching. my question is how I can get the location showing on map after clicking the button searching ? please give some sample code here.

Answer (score 0):

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
LocationManager locManager =
    (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
if(locManager.getBestProvider(criteria,true) != null){
    Location myLocation= locManager.getLastKnownLocation(locManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true));
    String latitude = Double.toString(myLocation.getLatitude());
    String longitude = Double.toString(myLocation.getLongitude());
    String altitude = Double.toString(myLocation.getAltitude());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want to animate your MapView to the coordinates the user puts in the EditText.

```
float latitude = new Float(lat.getText().toString()); //Check for errors here
float longitude = new Float(long.getText().toString()); //Check for errors here

//Create a GeoPoint, which takes lat/long in microdegrees:
GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int)(lat * 1E6), (int)(lng * 1E6));

//Use MapController to move your mapview
MapController controller = yourMapView.getController();
controller.animateTo(point);
//Or, without the scroll animation:
//controller.setCenter(point);
```

You can read more about the MapView and MapController classes here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapController
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapView

Comment: If you want the map to be moved when the search button is clicked, then put it in your search button's OnClickListener.